# Generate 3D "matrix" with Pandas, based on comparing two dataframes [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Good morning everyone. I am working with Python and Pandas.

I have two DataFrames, of the following type:

```
df_C = pd.DataFrame(data=[[-3,-1,-1], [5,3,3], [3,3,1], [-1,-1,-3], [-3,-1,-1], [2,3,1], [1,1,1]], columns=['C1','C2','C3'])

   C1  C2  C3
0  -3  -1  -1
1   5   3   3
2   3   3   1
3  -1  -1  -3
4  -3  -1  -1
5   2   3   1
6   1   1   1


df_F = pd.DataFrame(data=[[-1,1,-1,-1,-1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,-1,1],[1,-1,-1,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,-1],[1,1,1,-1,0],[1,1,-1,1,-1]], columns=['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5'])

   F1  F2  F3  F4  F5
0  -1   1  -1  -1  -1
1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1  -1   1
3   1  -1  -1  -1   1
4  -1   0   0  -1  -1
5   1   1   1  -1   0
6   1   1  -1   1  -1
```

I would like to be able to "cross" these two DataFrames, to generate or one in 3D, as follows:

[image: Matrix 3D]

The new data that is generated must compare the values of the **df_F** with the values of the **df_C**, taking into account the following:

- If both values are positive, generate 1
- If both values are negative, generate 1
- If one value is positive and the other negative, it generates 0
- If any of the values is zero, it generates None (NaN)

***True table***

Comparison of the data **df_C** vs **df_F**

```
df_C vs df_F = 3D
  +       +     1
  +       -     0
  +       0     None
  -       +     0
  -       -     1
  -       0     None
  0       +     None
  0       -     None
  0       0     None
```

You, who are experts in programming, could you please guide me, as I generate this matrix, I compare the values. I wish to do it with Pandas. *I have done it with loops (for) and conditions (if), but it is visually unpleasant* and I think that with Pandas it is more efficient and elegant.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Numpy [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Broadcast and multiply the values in `df_C` with the values from `df_F` in such a way that the shape of the resulting product matrix will be `(3, 7, 5)`, then test for the condition where the values in the product matrix are positive, negative or zero and assign the corresponding values `1`, `0` and `NaN` where the condition holds True

```
a = df_C.values.T[:, :, None] * df_F.values
a = np.select([a > 0, a < 0], [1, 0], np.nan)
```

---

```
array([[[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1., nan, nan,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0., nan],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1., nan, nan,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0., nan],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1., nan, nan,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0., nan],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: Shubham, thank you very much, Your solution is flawless, with a perfect explanation. Very elegant!